# PHP Proxy Script for Remote View

Tags: php, proxy

I'm trying to create a simple system that loads a website into an iframe to allow what normally would be blocked with cross-domain issues.

I've tried several proxy scripts loading http://www.website.com/index.php?url=http://www.other-site.com which seems to work except the return doesn't include scripts, css and other resources.

Is there a good script that will allow me to pull over the site, or a solid way to do it using cURL?

EDIT:

I actually got this working:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];

$content = file_get_contents($url);

// Fix href= statements 
$content = str_replace('src="','src="'.$url.'/',$content);
$content = str_replace('href="','href="'.$url.'/',$content);

echo $content;
```

Which works pretty well, there are 2 issues I'm running into:

1. The 'src' and 'href' replace work great on relatives, but I need to determine if the src is relative or absolute.
2. Links on the site stay on the original site, negating the 'proxy' which I think I can fix by just pointing back to http://www.website.com/index.php?url=http://www.other-site.com/[PATH]

Comment: You want client side (`iframe`) or server side (`php`) ?

Comment: Ultimately it will end up in an iframe (probably not pertinent to the question), but I'm doing this server site.

Comment: It's hard to create a good proxy script, since ajax was born things got realy hard. :)

Comment: It's not very trivial to do, probably you should use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) to parse the source and iterate over each tag that you want to replace the URL in (img, a etc) and have a function to determine if the path given is absolute, relative, or a complete URI and make the replacement as needed.  Even Apache's reverse proxy struggles with this in some situations so it'll take some work to get going but DOM should greatly simplify things.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's the direction I'll have to go. I'm not looking to do a whole lot one the page is loaded - mainly be able to pass in some JavaScript and CSS - it doesn't need to be a perfect 1-to-1, but close would be ideal.